# How to get model name & device version information from Chromecast custom receiver?

Tags: google-cast

Is there a way to find the model name and device version from the chromecast custom receiver application? On iOS, it appears this information is available from GCKDevice properites: modelName and deviceVersion -

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_device

I don't seem to find a way similar to do the same within the receiver. This would be helpful for gathering metrics type of data.

Answer (score 0):

There are no APIs on the receiver end to give you any device information such as the model name or version.